# Problem using `_Generic` with type-promotion

Tags: c

When calling a C-function its OK to call with a wider type by passing a narrower type that can be converted/promoted into the wider type.

For example:

```
void FooBar(uint32_t alpha);  // Function takes a 32-bit unsigned value

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t foo = 232;  // Variable foo is 16-bit unsigned
    FooBar(foo);         // 16-bit value gets auto-promoted to 32-bit value for the function call.
}
```

However, when I try to do this with `_Generic` in C11, auto-promotion seems to be lost:

```
#define FooBar(x) _Generic((x), uint32_t: FooBar_U32,\
                                double:   FooBar_DBL)(x)

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t foo = 232;  // Variable foo is 16-bit unsigned
    FooBar(foo);         // Try to promote a 16-bit to 32-bit value for FooBar_U32

    float nib = 3.14;
    FooBar(nib);  // Try to promote a float to a double for FooBar_DBL
}
```

The error is:

```
prog.c:7:28: error: ‘_Generic’ selector of type ‘short unsigned int’ is not compatible with any association
```

I would certainly expect a `short unsigned int` to be compatible with a `unsigned int` (32-bit).  So I do not understand the error message.

Is it impossible to use `_Generic` and get the benefits of type-promotion?
Am I doing something wrong here?

([Sample Code in IDEOne](https://ideone.com/lJ2tM7))

Comment: `_Generic` is not a function. It is a type of expression, effectively an operator.

Comment: `short unsigned int` is not compatible with `unsigned int`. “Compatible” does not mean one can be converted into the other without altering the value; it means, essentially, the two types are the same as far as the information about them is known. (E.g., one could be an array of 3 `int`, and the other could be an array of an unknown number of `int`.)

Comment: You could get the usual arithmetic promotions by using `0 ? (x) : (x)`, as in `_Generic(0 ? (x) : (x), uint32_t: FooBar_U32, double: FooBar_DL)(x)`. That will just give you the usual arithmetic promotions, not a conversion to other types such as `uint32_t` nor the default argument promotions (which would convert `float` to `double`).

Comment: You could just manually list `_Generic` cases for all types you want converted to the parameter type of each function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and suggestions.  Yet it seems this was 4 Comments that could/should have been a single Answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is "compatible" in the sense defined by the language specification, not in the much broader sense of pairs of types between which automatic conversions are defined, or where the integer promotions apply.  Relevant bits are spread across several sections of the specification, including at least sections 6.2.7 ("Compatible type and composite type"), 6.7.2 ("Type specifiers"), 6.7.3 ("Type qualifiers"), and 6.7.6 ("Declarators").  For arithmetic types other than enumerated types, however, "compatible type" simply boils down to *the same* type, including type qualifiers.

That is indeed very strict.  More so, for example, than is required by the strict aliasing rule for accessing an object of one type via an lvalue of a different type.  Much more so than is required for type matching across assignments or for matching function arguments to corresponding parameters. And no, `short unsigned int` is *not* compatible with `unsigned int` in this sense, not even in implementations where the two types are the same size.

> Is it impossible to use `_Generic` and get the benefits of
> type-promotion?

You get lvalue conversion, which drops type qualifiers, but generic associations are not among the places where the "usual arithmetic conversions" apply, nor do the automatic conversions performed in the context of assignments and function calls apply in this context (these are explicitly called out in the language spec where they apply).

This fine-grained approach is intentional.  The point is for generic associations to be able to distinguish between cases that are, among other things, assignment-compatible.  For example,

```
#define hton(x) _Generic((x), uint32_t: htonl, uint16_t: htons)(x)
```

> Am I doing something wrong here?

Your code does not conform to the language spec.  You can fix it by defining a generic association for each relevant type, and / or by converting the type of the operand of the generic selection to one of the types for which an association is provided.

One of the ways to do that would be to alter the expression in your generic selection to one that engages the usual arithmetic conversions (as opposed to the generic selection itself doing so), as was described in comments on the question.  But do note that the usual arithmetic conversions are narrower than the assignment conversions.  Also, that might not be useful in your particular case, because the the integer promotions of `uint32_t` and `uint16_t`  (as engaged as part of the usual arithmetic conversions) are not necessarily compatible.  It is reasonably likely the the former is `unsigned int` whereas the latter is `int`.